# -bash: /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve: No such file or directory

Tags: email, server, dovecot

After doing

```
apt install dovecot-imapd dovecot-sieve spamassassin spamc
```

and configuring `/etc/dovecot/docevot.conf`

which included adding the following text into the file (and commenting out !include conf.d/*.conf):

```
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = \$mail_plugins sieve
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = \$mail_plugins sieve
}
plugin {
    sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
    sieve_default = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
    sieve_dir = ~/.sieve
    sieve_global_dir = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/
}
```

I tried to run the following command and realized sieve was not around

```
echo "require [\"fileinto\", \"mailbox\"];
if header :contains \"X-Spam-Flag\" \"YES\"
        {
                fileinto \"Junk\";
        }" > /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
-bash: /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve: No such file or directory
```

this is what the directory looks like:

```
root@server:/etc/dovecot# ls /var/lib/dovecot/      
instances
root@server:/etc/dovecot# ls /var/lib/dovecot/instances 
/var/lib/dovecot/instances
```

I'm not sure if I should be creating the folder manually? Or if there was something wrong with the installation?

This is what I get with which

```
root@server:/etc/dovecot# which dovecot
/usr/sbin/dovecot
root@server:/etc/dovecot# which sieve
/usr/bin/sieve
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there only thing you have to do is creating the directory:

```
mkdir /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/
```

after this execute your echo command:

```
echo "require [\"fileinto\", \"mailbox\"];
if header :contains \"X-Spam-Flag\" \"YES\"
        {
                fileinto \"Junk\";
        }" > /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
```

and this will create the file `default.sieve` for you and paste the code in there.